# Работа с функцией preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как функции `preg_match`, разрешить пропускать только такой шаблон: 
`TDA 123456789`?

Тоесть латинские буквы `TDA`, пробел, и любые девять цифр (`0-9`). В таком же порядке.

Answer (score 1):

немного расплывчато условие:)

но может угадал

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/TDA\\s[0-9]{9}/', 'TDA 123123123', $matches);
```

Если имелось ввиду, что буквы TDA могут быть в любом порядке, главное, что бы три штуки, тогда

```
$returnValue = preg_match('/[TDA]{3}\\s[0-9]{9}/', 'TDA 123123123', $matches);
```

Comment: Первый вариант должен подойти. Буквы должны быть только в данном порядке. Спасибо!

Comment: Если нет, тогда просто приведите 5-10 вариантов исходной строки, которые должны пройти.

Comment: <?
Показывает верно, даже если условие не верно. Почему?

$matches = "TDL 123123120";

if(preg_match('/TDA\\s[0-9]{9}/', 'TDA 123123123', $matches) )

{ echo "верно"; }

else
{echo "не верно";}




Вот валидные строки,которые должны проходить:


TDA 123456789 - верно

TD 184623782 - не верно

TDL 472678217 - не верно

TDA412348562 - не верно

TDA 124 - не верно

TDA 123456789000 - не верно

В общем: Обязательно три буквы ,строго в порядке TDA . Далее обязательно пробел, далее любые девять цифр. Небольше и не меньше.







?>

Comment: потому, что неверно используете:)
`$matches` - это массив того, что будет найдено. Но в данном случае оно не нужно. А вот второй параметр функции `preg_match` - это и есть строка, которую нужно сравнивать.

    $s = "TDL 123123120";
    if(preg_match('/^TDA\s[0-9]{9}$/', $s) )
    { echo "верно"; }
    else {echo "не верно";}

символы `^` `$` нужны, так как иначе будет совпадать и строка вида `fffTDA 12312378999768478`

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Все не могу найти материал, либо справочник по работе с preg_match. Тему можно закрывать.

Comment: @ptwp Дж.Фридл «Регулярные выражения»

Comment: >Все не могу найти материал

http://citforum.ru/internet/perl/regexp/

>справочник по работе с preg_match

http://www.php.su/preg_match